# Example for sync.WaitGroup correct?

Tags: go, goroutine

Is this example usage of `sync.WaitGroup` correct? It gives the expected result, but I am unsure about the `wg.Add(4)` and the position of `wg.Done()`. Does it make sense to add the four goroutines at once with `wg.Add()`?

http://play.golang.org/p/ecvYHiie0P

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func dosomething(millisecs time.Duration, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    duration := millisecs * time.Millisecond
    time.Sleep(duration)
    fmt.Println("Function in background, duration:", duration)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(4)
    go dosomething(200, &wg)
    go dosomething(400, &wg)
    go dosomething(150, &wg)
    go dosomething(600, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Result (as expected):

```
Function in background, duration: 150ms
Function in background, duration: 200ms
Function in background, duration: 400ms
Function in background, duration: 600ms
Done
```

Comment: What if dosomething() crashes before it can do wg.Done()?

Comment: I realize this is old, but for future people, I would recommend an initial `defer wg.Done()` call at the start of the function.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Yes, this example is correct. It is important that the `wg.Add()` happens before the `go` statement to prevent race conditions. The following would also be correct:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go dosomething(200, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go dosomething(400, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go dosomething(150, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go dosomething(600, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

However, it is rather pointless to call `wg.Add` over and over again when you already know how many times it will be called.

---

`Waitgroups` panic if the counter falls below zero. The counter starts at zero, each `Done()` is a `-1` and each `Add()` depends on the parameter. So, to ensure that the counter never drops below and avoid panics, you need the `Add()` to be *guaranteed* to come before the `Done()`.

In Go, such guarantees are given by the [memory model](http://golang.org/ref/mem).

The memory model states that all statements in a single goroutine appear to be executed in the same order as they are written. It is possible that they won't actually be in that order, but the outcome will be as if it was. It is also guaranteed that a [goroutine doesn't run until after the `go` statement that calls it](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_4). Since the `Add()` occurs before the `go` statement and the `go` statement occurs before the `Done()`, we know the `Add()` occurs before the `Done()`.

If you were to have the `go` statement come before the `Add()`, the program may operate correctly. However, it would be a race condition because it would not be guaranteed.

Comment: I have a question over this one: wouldn't it be better to `defer wg.Done()` so that we are sure that it gets called irrespective of the route the goroutine takes? Thanks.

Comment: if you purely wanted to make sure the function didn't return before all the go routines were finished then yes defer would be preferred. just usually the entire point of a wait group is to wait till all the work is done to then do something with the results you were waiting for.

Comment: If you don't use `defer` and one of your goroutines fails to call `wg.Done()` ... won't your `Wait` simply block forever?  This sounds like it could easily introduce a hard-to-find bug into your code...

Answer (score 30):

I would recommend embeding the `wg.Add()` call into the `doSomething()` function itself, so that if you adjust the number of times it's called, you don't have to separately adjust the add parameter manually which could lead to an error if you update one but forget to update the other (in this trivial example that is unlikely, but still, I personally believe it to be better practice for code re-use).

As Stephen Weinberg points out in [his answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208908/2352063), you do have to increment the waitgroup *prior* to spawning the gofunc, but you can accomplish this easily by wrapping the gofunc spawn inside the `doSomething()` function itself, like this:

```
func dosomething(millisecs time.Duration, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        duration := millisecs * time.Millisecond
        time.Sleep(duration)
        fmt.Println("Function in background, duration:", duration)
        wg.Done()
    }()
}
```

Then you can call it without the `go` invocation, e.g.:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    dosomething(200, &wg)
    dosomething(400, &wg)
    dosomething(150, &wg)
    dosomething(600, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

As a playground: http://play.golang.org/p/WZcprjpHa_

Answer (score 24):

- small improvement based on Mroth answer
- using defer for Done is safer

> ```
>   func dosomething(millisecs time.Duration, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
>   wg.Add(1)
>   go func() {
>       defer wg.Done()
>       duration := millisecs * time.Millisecond
>       time.Sleep(duration)
>       fmt.Println("Function in background, duration:", duration)
>   }()
> }
>
> func main() {
>   var wg sync.WaitGroup
>   dosomething(200, &wg)
>   dosomething(400, &wg)
>   dosomething(150, &wg)
>   dosomething(600, &wg)
>   wg.Wait()
>   fmt.Println("Done")
> }
> ```