# Max element - fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, synchronization, deadlock, goroutine

On my machine `runtime.NUMCPU` is 4

Below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    "github.com/myhub/a/expressions"
)

var list = make([]int, 1e5)

func main() {

    value := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1e5; i++ {
        list[i] = value // sample list
        value = value + 1
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    var max1 int
    go func() {
        max1 = expressions.Max(list[0 : 1e5/4-1])
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    var max2 int
    go func() {
        max2 = expressions.Max(list[1e5/4 : 1e5/2-1])
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    var max3 int
    go func() {
        max3 = expressions.Max(list[1e5/2 : 3*1e5/4-1])
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    var max4 int
    go func() {
        max4 = expressions.Max(list[3*1e5/4 : 1e5-1])
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(max1, max2, max3, max4)

}
```

---

```
package expressions

func Max(list []int) int {

    length := len(list)
    if length > 1 {

        if list[0] > list[length-1] {

            return Max(list[:length-1])
        } else {

            return Max(list[1:length])
        }
    }
    return list[0]
}
```

---

gives error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc00001a0a8)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x42
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc00001a0a0)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x64
main.main()
        /home/machine1/code/src/github.com/myhub/a/Main.go:41 +0x1b5
exit status 2
```

---

For list of length `make([]int, 1e5)` having unsorted data,

How to split the load of `list` across four OS threads? to find max element

Comment: lookup sync.WaitGroup    .....  specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208725/example-for-sync-waitgroup-correct

Comment: @ScottStensland `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` after waiting on single `list`

Answer (score 2):

U need to call wg.Done() in gorutines
For example:

```
wg.Add(1)
var max4 int
go func() {
    max4 = expressions.Max(list[3*1e5/4 : 1e5-1])
    wg.Done()
}()
```

Comment: This goes sequential processing of go routines. isn't it?

Comment: Nope, since wg.Wait() on the end of function.